# Facebook authorization in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

How do I implement a Facebook authorization? I have no idea where to start. I have seen numerous examples in PHP but none in C#.

Comment: I noticed you have the c# sdk. Would it be possible for you to do the authorization in javascript?

Comment: Please can you give some information as to what you have tried, what you have read etc. There is so much info on Facebook authorisation on both this website, and http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here: http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the `Facebook javascript sdk` (Much easier IMO, and you have asp.net as a tag so i am making assumptions) you could try something like this:

```
//Facebook iFrame include
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: YourID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    authorize();

}

/*
* Facebook Authorization
*/
function authorize (){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
            // logged in and connected user, carry on
        } else {
            // no user session available, Lets ask for perms
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'permissions.request',
                perms: your permissions
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response && response.session != null) {
                    //User accepted permissions
                } else {
                   //User did not accept permissions
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```